# ToggleGroup in Unity3D, which is the active one?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, toggle, dropdown

How do we know which toggle is active from the toggle groups?

Unity Doc says use `ToggleGroup.ActiveToggles` but I can't understand how to use it?

Comment: Hi Paul, note that you have to TICK an answer - not just vote it up. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
private void Example()
  {
  Toggle theActiveToggle = yourToggleGroup.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault();
  Debug.Log("It worked! " + theActiveToggle.gameObject.name);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is throwing an error that activeToggles() is method and not active in following contex

Comment: using System.Linq;
public class Topic : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string topictext;
    public ToggleGroup Topiz;
      Toggle maybe1;
 // Use this for initialization
 void prove() 
    {

         maybe1 = Topiz.ActiveToggles.FirstOrDefault();
 }
What is wrong still throwing an error

Comment: @paulPATIL  `Toggle theActiveToggle = yourToggleGroup.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault();` I think you forgot the '()' after the `ActiveToggles`. That's just it. It should work after that is added.

Comment: Just a typo. Did even notice that when I first saw your answer until the guy started complaining.

Comment: Thanks for your help.